# jquery function can not be defined even though it is imported

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I am using [Evan plaice jquery-csv libary](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv) but I am running into a lot of trouble to get it working at the moment due to his code not updated after google code is deprecated.

I am using the one of his example where you upload a csv file and it will parse the document so that the csv file will be shown on the webpage [Demo here](http://evanplaice.github.io/jquery-csv/examples/file-handling.html).

I downloaded his code from github but then since the googlecode he imported is not working anymore I put the file jquery.csv.js in the same folder as the file I am using. In the jquery.csv.js, there is a function being called which is toArray in the html file. I deleted the line where it is used to be `<script src="http://jquery-csv.googlecode.com/git/src/jquery.csv.js"></script>` and added `<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.csv.js"></script>` However, for whatever reason it complains that toArry is not defined.

Basically the code is like this:

```
function printTable(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(file);
  reader.onload = function(event){
    var csv = event.target.result;
    var data = $.csv.toArrays(csv);  << The line that has problem.
    var html = '';
    for(var row in data) {
      html += '<tr>\r\n';
      for(var item in data[row]) {
        html += '<td>' + data[row][item] + '</td>\r\n';
      }
      html += '</tr>\r\n';
    }
    $('#contents').html(html);
  };
  reader.onerror = function(){ alert('Unable to read ' + file.fileName); };
}
```

In the developer console it indicates:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toArrays' of undefined
>       at FileReader.reader.onload (file:///Users/Jace/Downloads/jquery-csv-master/examples/file-handling.html:75:25)

Comment: Check the path of `jquery.csv.js` file, if you have put in same folder then use `src="jquery.csv.js"`and whats the sequence of the the files?

Comment: I used src="jquery.csv.js" at the beginning but it still did not work. What do you mean by sequence. Sorry I am a little new to jquery. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: 1. `<script src="./jquery.js"></script>`  2. `<script src="./jquery.csv.js"></script>`3. Your script in question

Comment: Oh I don't think I have jQuery.js. I basically used [link](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/blob/master/examples/file-handling.html) this file and put the jQuery.csv.js in the same folder and thats it. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're problem is that when you removed the reference to the jquery-csv library hosted on Google Code and included your local version, you put it above the reference to jQuery itself. That's when I notice the error you're describing. The order you load in your JavaScript files does matter. When for example JavaScript code in file `B.js` is depending on code in `A.js`, `A.js` needs to be specified *before* `B.js`.

So basically check if the order you're specifying the files in in your HTML file is correct:

```
<body>
    <!-- HTML... -->

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.csv.js"></script> <!-- The "./" is not used here -->

    <script>
        // Code...
    </script>
</body>
```

Also, the `./` in front is not needed and not common. I've never used it in any case. ;)

I hope that makes it a bit more clear to you!